# How do I configure Windows 10 Quick Access menu to show only items i want?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-quick-access

I have added items to the windows 10 Quick Access menu.  They no longer show.  Instead, recently viewed items are showing in its place.  As I remove items I do not want from the quick access menu, other recently viewed items show.  Eventually after much deleting I then see the items I manually added to the quick access menu.

How do I configure windows so that items do not dynamically add to the quick access menu, and that the only items that show are items I manually added?

Answer (score 2):

To control whether or not quick access menu shows recently viewed items...

1. Open File Explorer In left-hand pane, right-click item 'Quick Access'
2. Select menu choice 'Options' (A dialog box will appear)
3. In the tab 'General' in the section 'Privacy' clear the checkboxes
   'Show recently used files in Quick access' and 'Show frequently used folders in Quick Access'
4. click button 'Clear'
5. Click button 'Apply'
6. Click button 'OK'

[image]