# How do I prevent file explorer from automatically adding things to Quick Access?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, user-folders, windows-10-quick-access

Windows File Explorer always pins folders that I frequently use to Quick Access.  At the moment, I like my quick access bar how it is and I don't want it to be changed at all. Right now I have to manually remove the auto-added folders from quick access to keep it how I want it.

How can I stop file explorer from automatically adding folders to quick access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable recent files in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1031638/disable-recent-files-in-windows-10)

Comment: Additional duplicate: [How do I configure Windows 10 Quick Access menu to show only items I want?](https://superuser.com/questions/1306526/how-do-i-configure-windows-10-quick-access-menu-to-show-only-items-i-want/1306530#1306530)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Search for `File Explorer Options` and uncheck `Show frequently used folders in Quick Access` under Privacy. Press apply and then OK.